# What is the definition of finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

To be specific, here is an example.

Note that $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group.

> Definition 1. (Lang)
>
> Let $G$ be a group and $S\subset G$.
>
> If $G$ is the intersection of all subgroups $H$ of $G$ containing $S$, then "$\forall x\in S, x$ is called a generator of $G$.
>
> And we say, $G$ is finitely generated iff there exists such $S$ which is finite

.

> Definition2. (Rotman)
>
> Let $(S|R)$ be a presentation for a group $G$. (This means that $G$ is isomorphic to a quotient of the free group $F(S)$ by the normal closure of $R$.
>
> In this case $\forall x\in S$, $x$ is called a generator of $G$.
>
> If $G$ has a presentation suh that $S$ is finite, then we call $G$ is finitely generated.

Which one is the usual definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lang's definition is more usual than Rotman's..

More than that, usual equivalent condition we mean when we say finitely generated is

$G=\langle g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n\rangle=\{g_1^{r_1}g_2^{r_2}\cdots g_n^{r_n} : r_i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: Are they equivalent?

Comment: yes, they are....

Comment: How does Rotman's definition imply Lang's definition??

Comment: are you familiar with free groups??

Comment: I learned free group like days ago so I'm not quite familiar yet.. But I know its properties such as universal mapping property

Comment: In Rotman's definition, there is a mapping from $F(S)$ onto $G$. The image of $S$ under that map is a subset of $G$, which will be the $S$ of Lang's definition.

Comment: I can not make it more clear that what Harald said in his comment....

Comment: I get it. Thank you:)

Comment: Happy to help :)